# C# - MVC - Issue with reference a class library project to main project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I try to do an ASP.NET MVC project (.NET 4.5.2 framework) with multiple layers (business layer, data access layer, entities layer and main layer).

My business layer is a class library project. So when I try to references this project from the main layer, I get this error:

> The project "Business Layer" has .netstandard 2.0 as target. Can't references to .NETFramework Version =v4.5.2 project as target

This is a `web.config` section

```
<configuration>
.
.
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>

<\configuration>
```

Does someone know how to do this reference?

Comment: Where did you get the web config file from? Is that the one for the project your trying to add reference to or the one your adding ? It sounds like the business layer project is set to a different version of  .net framework and you need to go into the project settings and change to same version as other project

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have created your business library using the .net core library template instead of the .net framework one. The easiest thing to do, is to create a new library using the .net framework template, and then copy your source files into the new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem encountered is due to the different version support because you are trying to reference a .Net Standard 2.0 library to **.Net Framework 4.5.2**, you can refer to the table below, you need to upgrade your project **.Net Framework 4.5.2** to **.Net Framework 4.6.1** .

[image: .Net implementation support]